# How To Import / Export SQL Database Tables Programmatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, import

I am trying to import all of a Database's information to another Database just as I would when doing it with the user interface.

I tried to do it with a large .SQL file generated by one of my custom inhouse programs, but the server runs out of memory due to a 300MB .sql file.

How can I utilize SQL Server's Import feature via code in VB.Net?

Comment: Can you use replication, service broker?

Comment: Why don't you just run a loop through the tables of the first database and grab a few thousand lines at a time and send them to the second database? Eventually all will be sent over. Do you know how to connect to the database and read in data in vb.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use other methods as data replications between servers or another "more Admin" approcach, but if you want to do it programatically you can create a DTS (data transformation package), then use a scheduler like [quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) and execute your DTS with the schedule you need it.

```
Dim dtsp As New DTS.Package
    dtsp.LoadFromSQLServer _
        ServerName:="MyServer", _
        ServerUserName:="MyUserID", _
        ServerPassword:="MyPassword", _
        PackageName:="DTSDemo"
    dtsp.Execute
```

take a look to [the reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315661/en) this may help you out.

That only [will work](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500429.aspx) on **previous** versions to SQL 2012.

as an alternative you may want to call a SSIS package so take a look to [this tutorial](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/09/call-ssis-2012-package-within-net.html) practically the logic is the same whatever you decide to use a DTS or a SSIS package.